# openh264dec caps negotiation failure

Tags: gstreamer

I'm facing a caps negotiation failure to `openh264dec`'s sink. Looking at the docs, I see:

```
video/x-h264:
  stream-format: byte-stream
      alignment: au
        profile: { (string)constrained-baseline, (string)baseline, (string)main, (string)high, (string)constrained-high, (string)progressive-high }
```

And the failure is:

```
openh264dec:sink

caps video/x-h264, 
stream-format=(string)byte-stream, 
alignment=(string)au, 
width=(int)240, 
height=(int)320, 
framerate=(fraction)0/1, 
chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, 
bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, 
bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, 
colorimetry=(string)1:0:0:0, 
parsed=(boolean)true, 
profile=(string)baseline, 
level=(string)3.1

not accepted

Internal data stream error. 2023-09-27T15:49:35UTC
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)   2023-00.172Z
Internal data stream error. 2023-09-27T15:49:35UTC
```

Is there an obvious issue here?